# c# controllers post filter

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm just seeking some 'best practice' information here.
Say I have a controller e.g

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Title,Content")] Models.MyReport report)
```

On the form (view) I give give the following

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

So if they click Create it creates the report, cancel cancels it and returns them to the list screen (lets say)

Is there a filter much like [HttpPost] or [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  that I should use.

Or should I just use the `request.form[action]` within the controller to work out my action from there?

Comment: Why not just make the 'Cancel' a link that redirects to your index page (there is no point submitting all your data if your just going to throw it away)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right so the answer is thus

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Title,Content")] Models.MyReport report,string action)
```

Then within the controller you can then do

```
if(action == 'create') {
   //create action
}
else if(action="cancel") {
 //do something else
}
```

There is an additional lesson to be learnt here, you can add as many 'custom' variables to the controller and c# /mvc will map the get/post variables to them.

The ones that you set by the displayFor will have a name that c# /mvc will use 
in the object.

Answer (score 0):

A form should only have one submit input. Change your cancel button to be of type "button" or even make, make it a link:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
```

If your controller action is decorated with HttpPost attribute then the form type should be post.

If you have the antiforgery attribute then the **first input** on the form should be a hidden input with the token. There is a Html Extension to render this for you.

Comment: Mmm, yes I do use the [HttpPost] and the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] so that does help. But I'm afraid I'm not signing up the the 'one button' per form argument. I admit in this instance the cancel could be a link, but perhaps lets say that I have another button called 'preview' and the Content had some 'bb' code. (This could be a comment) now I want to send this object back to the razor frontend and have it process the bbcode (using a helper). This would require 2 buttons would it not? Or maybe 2 buttons - one to email to friend 1, another to friend 2. What then?

Comment: Not "one button", but "one submit input" (which typically takes the form of a button).  Other buttons can be added without being a submit input.  In the case of "email to one friend" or "email to two friends", this is essentially a piece of information that should be submitted (and further acted upon internall), not an actual action that would be driven from the form.

Comment: Exactly. You can have as many buttons as you want, but only one should be an input with the type of "submit"

Comment: You can have as many submit buttons as you want. If they have the same `name` attribute (say "action") then just add a parameter `string action` to the method and it will be the value of the clicked button.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's not the way it's meant to work.

Comment: @JohnMc, What do you mean _not the way it's meant to work_? It not uncommon to have forms with multiple submit buttons and its perfectly valid html. A submit button is no different from any other form control (except that only the one that clicked has its value submitted)

Comment: I'm with Stephen on this, but feeling we are going away from the question.
Stephen, could you just given an example with the parameter and the string. i.e flesh it out to a answer with the example to a controller function